# Transposing an array (CS 101)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to transpose an array from 4x2 to 2x4, per these instructions"

"Given a 2-D array arr1 of ints, return a 2-D array arr2, that is the transpose of arr1. 
A transpose is when you make the rows of the arrays into columns. That is, arr1[n][m] = 
arr2[m][n]."

The solution I made follows:

```
public int[][] transpose(int[][] arr1){
    int[][] arr2;

    arr2 = new int [arr1[0].length][arr1.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr1[0].length; j++){
            arr2[j][i] = arr1[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I quite understand the array notation though, when the code references `arr1[0]` and `arr1` to access rows vs columns.  Does `arr1[0].length` access the length of the first column, where `arr1.length` accesses the length of the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say you have (4x2 2-D array)

```
int[][] arr1 = {{1,2},
                {3,4},
                {5,6},
                {7,8}
                };
```

Then the value of each is:

```
arr1[0].length // 2
arr1.length    // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does arr1[0].length access the length of the first column, where arr1.length accesses the length of the first row?

It depends one exactly how you're viewing the array in terms of "rows" and "columns".

The `int[][]` type is an array of arrays. Each element of that array is an `int[]`, which can be a different size to all the others. So `arr1.Length` is the number of "nested" arrays, and `arr1[0].Length` is the length of the first nested array. If you're viewing each nested array as a row, then `arr1.Length` is the number of rows, and `arr1[0].Length` is the number of columns in the first row - and you're basically assuming that each element of `arr1` has the same length.

Answer (score 0):

opposite.

```
arr1[0]
```

represents first row. this way it gives the length of first row, i.e. number of columns.